# Find the distribution of a function of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let be $X$ a continuous random variable with distribution $F_X$. Let be
$Y= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
X & if  \ X\leq a \\
a & if\  X >a
\end{array}
\right.$

find the distribution of $Y$ in terms of $F_X$. Is $Y$ a mixed random variable?

I want to know if my answer is correct:

By the definition of $Y$:

$F_Y(y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
P(X<y) & if  \ y\leq a \\
P(Y\leq a)+P(a<Y<y) & if\  y >a
\end{array}
\right.$

Since $P(a<Y<y)=0$ we can write

$F_Y(y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
P(X<y)=F_X(y) & if  \ y\leq a \\
P(Y< a)+P(Y=a)+0=P(X<a)+P(X>a) & if\  y >a
\end{array}
\right.$

Since $X$ is a continuous random variable:

$F_Y(y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
P(X<y)=F_X(y) & if  \ y\leq a \\
P(P(X<a)+P(X>a)=F(a)+(1-F(a)=1 & if\  y >a
\end{array}
\right.$

$F_Y(y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
F_X(y) & if  \ y\leq a \\
1 & if\  y >a
\end{array}
\right.$

Finally, $Y$ is a mixed random variable because the set of discontinuities={a} and $F(a)-F(a-)=1-F(a)\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditioning:
\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leqslant y)\\
&=P(Y\leqslant y|X\leqslant a)P(X\leqslant a)+P(Y\leqslant y|X>a)P(X> a)\\
&=P(X\leqslant y|X\leqslant a)P(X\leqslant a)+P(Y\leqslant y|X>a)P(X> a)\\
&=P(X\leqslant y, X\leqslant a)+P(Y\leqslant y|X>a)P(X> a)\\
&=\begin{cases}
P(X\leqslant y)&\text{if }\ y\leqslant a\\
P(X\leqslant a)+P(X>a)&\text{if }\ y> a
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
F_X(y)&\text{if }\ y\leqslant a\\
1&\text{if }\ y> a
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: your answer allow the possibility that $F_Y(a)<1$ but all the values of $Y$ are less than or equal to $a$ so I think that $F_Y(y)$ must be equal to 1, why this is not true in your answer?

Comment: You are correct; fixed now.